# React JS: Rendering Blank page instead of rendering the component in route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, mern

In React JS App there is forgot password functionality, on entering email end users get password reset link if the user's email exists in DB. When user clicks the link inside email it gets redirect and load blank screen. I can't figure out the problem, I had checked all routes and looks like perfect.

This is ResetPassword Component where user can enter set his new password.

```
const ResetPassword = (props) => {
    const userId = props.match.params.id
    const [password,setPassword] = useState({
        password: '', confirmPassword: ''
    })
    const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_baseUrl
    const changePassUrl = `${baseUrl}/user/reset/${userId}`
    const history = useHistory()

    const resetPassword = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const options = {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(password)
        }
        await fetch(changePassUrl, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => {
            console.log('Success:', user);
            if(user.status===true){
                toast.success('Password changed Successfully. Login with New Password',{position: 'top-center', autoClose: 8000})
                history.push('/login')
            }
            else if(user.status === false){
                toast.error('Please try again!',{position: 'top-center', autoClose: 8000})
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
```

App.js route of above component.

```
 <Route exact path='/reset/:id' component={ResetPassword}/>
```

Node API that sends the reset link via NodeMailer.

```
module.exports.resetUserPassword  = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email},
        (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    status: false,
                    message: 'some error occured in Finding User.',
                    error: err,
                });
            }
            if (users) {
                const url = process.env.Url
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: process.env.mailHost,
                    port: 587,
                    auth: {
                      user: process.env.mailUser,
                      pass: process.env.mailPass
                    }
                  });
                  
                  var mailOptions = {
                    from: process.env.mailUser,
                    to: users.email,
                    subject: 'Password Reset Link',
                    html: `
                    <div style='color: #000'>
                    <h2>Hello ${users.fullName},</h2>
                    <h3>A request has been received to change the password for your Jobs@MyCityMyStore Account.</h3>
                    <h3>Click <a href="${url}/reset/${users._id}">here</a> to reset your password</h3>
                    <p>If you did not initiate this request, Please contact us immediately at </p><a href='#'>support@support.com</a><br/>
                    <p>Thank you.</p>
                    <p>support@support Team</p>
                    </div>`
                  };
                  
                  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                    if (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                    } else {
                      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                    }
                });
                res.status(200).json({ status: true, email: users.email });
            }else{
                res.status(200).json({status: false, data: 'User not found '+users})
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: No one can really help you if you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of what your app is doing.

Comment: @DrewReese added the code.

Comment: What if you manually navigate to your "/reset/:id" path? Does your `Router` correctly match it and render `ResetPassword` component? Is `process.env.Url` for the email the correct root?

Comment: @rutvikpankhania, Please make sure, there is no error in browser console.

Comment: if I manually go to any route it still shows blank page

Comment: In my Local it works fine but when I deploy this to Heroku, I am facing this issue.

Comment: @rutvikpankhania, Is it forming the correct URL in Heroku?